# Use Cython DLL in Visual Basic

Tags: python, vb.net, cython

Is it possible to use a Python script compiled with Cython into a dll in Visual Basic? All I found was how to use C++ dlls.

Comment: Did you try? You should just be able to include it as you would a C++ dll if it's unmanaged I would think?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would have to be either a .NET Assembly or a COM object to be used.